# Removing unwanted white boarder surrounding full page

Tags: html, css

My site is https://ized.online

I have tried setting the margin and padding of h1 and my divs to 0px in my CSS, but the border remains, and it seems like its either my main container div or the CSS properties of  or , as inspecting the element links back to both of them in a non-descriptive form, and similarly trying to set margin or padding to 0 gives no result.

What would you suggest to remove the white boarder surrounding my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each browser has its own set of preset css rules, on divs, body, etc. try using something like https://github.com/csstools/sanitize.css which removes them, or simply use

```
body{ margin: 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to remove default margins from the body: `body{margin:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

In css you can see
border: (px style color)
And that should solve the issue if you delete that settings.
Also, border: none on the element should be an option, but probably you missed the border settings.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is **CSS** you need. I suggest you to look up how **position: absolute** works with properties **top, bottom, left, right**.

```
.text2 {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    color: grey;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
}
```